# Wordpress - Load posts by ID returns NULL

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a page template with a $_GET variable to return information for a single post that's part of a custom post type but it doesn't return anything. Any ideas?

```
         <?php
          $args = array(
          'p' => $_GET['funeralID'], // id of a page, post, or custom type
          'post_type'  => 'post'
          );

          $video_post = new WP_Query($args);

          while ( $video_post->have_posts() ) : $video_post->the_post(); ?>


            <?php the_field('archive_video_link'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add the variable to the WordPress' array of 'recognized query variables'...

```
add_action('init','add_my_vars');
function add_my_vars() { 
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('funeralID'); 
}
```

Then the value of 'funeralID' can be found via `get_query_var('funeralID');` See [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

Comment: thanks but that didn't do anything to fix the issue.

Comment: @MG1 Oh, was the problem not getting the query variable? I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish but maybe it's the fact that you're using 
 `'post_type'  => 'post'`,
If it's a custom post type I think you should use that instead of 'post'.